# Draw text in QGLWidget when using raw OpenGL

Tags: qt, qt4

I am writing Qt app that wraps an external 3D engine.I use QGLWidget to encapsulate the engine API.I don't use any Qt GL API methods though I do create GL context using Qt API:

```
QGLFormat format;
format.setProfile(QGLFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
format.setVersion(4,2);
format.setDoubleBuffer(true);
format.setSwapInterval(1);
```

Now,I was searching for a way to draw text in the viewport and found Qt's [rendeText()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.1/qglwidget.html).

I have tried to use it but no text is begin drawn.
That is how I do it:

```
    qglColor(Qt::black);
    this->renderText(50, 50, "Some text");
```

What do I miss here?

Btw, my depth buffer is off.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method to draw text in my OpenGL widgets:

```
void myGL_Widget::OGL_Draw_Text(QString text,float x,float y, float z, float red, float green, float blue)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(red, green, blue);
        renderText(x, y, z, text);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

Comment: tried this too.Doesn't work.May be it works only with fixed pipeline?

Comment: Qt uses OpenGL 2.0 with shaders. But OpenGL 3+ is quite recent or even not available yet. Qt5 minimum. So it might be that it tries to use GL2 while your engine already switched to a GL3 context. See also your format parameter.